# Hello Analytics example generates 403 error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I am a "newbie" to the Google Analytics API and I am trying to get the "Hello Analytics" example working.

I followed [their steps](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js)
to create the test web page but I got no results.

When I go to my web page, I see the title, the "Sign in" button and the text area below where the result should appear.  When I press "Sign in", that seems to work; the button changes to say "Signed In".  However, no results appear.

I am using FireFox so I right-clicked on the text area and selected "Inspect Element"; this shows this error message:

> Object { result: Object, body: "{   "error": {     "code": 403,    …",
>   headers:  Object, status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden" }

I think this is a permission error but do not know how to correct it.

Here is my file HelloAnalytics.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</title>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="959582115031-ardmn5vsir7kbcp0dme4d4n1p45bd649.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</h1>

<p>
  <!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `queryReports()` on success. -->
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="queryReports"></div>
</p>

<!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>
  // Replace with your view ID.
  var VIEW_ID = '92320289';

  // Query the API and print the results to the page.
  function queryReports() {
    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: 'ga:sessions'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

  function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  }
</script>

<!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to understand how to use the Google Analytics API to do simple queries.

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server?

Comment: how to do pagination in google analytics API?

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY got it to work!

I was trying to use the API to get data for the Google sample site ("Google Merchandise Store").  I was trying to think of possible reasons for the permission error, and it occurred to me that maybe Google didn't allow Analytics API calls for that web site.

So I went through the effort of setting up my own test web site with Google's Javascript tracking code in it, then defining a new project, enabling the API for it, creating credentials (a client ID) and getting the view ID for my web site.  With the new client ID and view ID in my HelloAnalytics.html page, it worked perfectly.

So my guess was correct: Google does NOT permit API calls to get data for its "Google Merchandise Store" sample website.  They REALLY should mention this on [their "quickstart" page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js) because a "newbie" (like me) wouldn't know that!

I thought I should post my solution because I'm sure that somebody else will run into this problem in the future.

FYI- I have HelloAnalytics.html running on a web server.  I am using free web space provided by my ISP.

Comment: Yes, you can't make API calls to the Google Merchandise Store, its at the bottom of this help article https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en

Comment: Oh yes they do say that there; never saw that page.  Thanks

Comment: On the quickstart guides they also state at the very bottom "Note: To successfully run this sample you will need to have at least one Google Analytics property and view." One could reading of that is that you must have a property and view that belongs to you.